# authentication is required when I try having an access to the google play store

Tags: google-play-store

I am not able to install my favourite games such as ZOMBIES KILLER 3D. Whenever i ha ve tried installing this games the pla store send me a message and that is "authentication is required you need to sign in your google account"
I am kindly requesting you solving my problem.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Please check with our [google-play-store tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/google-play-store/info), which holds a list of error messages and possible solutions. Then come back here and either [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17845/192154) (when solved) or [edit] it to include what you've tried and where you're stuck. Thanks, and good luck!

Comment: PS: A [little search revealed answers](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=[google-play-store]+authentication+required+answers%3A1): [Getting “Authentication is required” when trying to access the Play Store](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/20369/16575) / [Authentication Required](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/98728/16575)

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear the data for the Play Store app.
Navigate to Settings >> Apps >> Search for "Play Store"
Then Click "Clear Data"
Hope that helps!!